# Mini Filter driver communication with windows service

Tags: c++, c, winapi, driver, minifilter

I am creating a mini-filter driver. In that i communicate with user mode application to get the some of the data form user. i communicate with user mode using "communication port". i tried to communicate with user mode application it worked fine.

One the suggestion i got form others is to use windows service to fetch the data since it will always be running and we want user mode application to run always.

My question is

1) Can i create "communication port" in windows service?

2) If i create windows service, how to get specific user information. i mean, when i send the request to service how service come to know from which user session data needs to be fetched?

3) which one is better, i mean user mode or windows service is better solution.

Comment: A Windows service pretty much falls under the term "user-mode application". It uses a certain API to identify itself as a service,  may run with SYSTEM privileges, and may not be able to display a UI, but otherwise it is pretty much a user-mode application like any other. Note that a service is not associated with a specific user session.

Comment: ok, Form mini filter driver can we get form which session we got the call in mini filter driver.

Comment: There is no session. A service does not interact with a user. There is a single service process and it runs regardless of how many users (including none) are logged into the machine.

Comment: ok, if i want to communicate with user mode i need to impersonate that user, so that i can get user specific data. but only thing is for which user to impersinate

Comment: If you need to be that user, just run a regular application as that user. Impersonating a user would require obtaining a token for that user, which is only [easily] done via LogonUser (which requires a password) or by finding an existing token for that user from a program already running as that user.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Can i create "communication port" in windows service?

Yes you can create it in service.

> 2) If i create windows service, how to get specific user information. i mean, when i send the request to service how service come to know from which user session data needs to be fetched?

Service does runs under system account and not under any logged in user. So to show popup or dialog to current logged in user, you can look at [`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar api to get console session.

> 3) which one is better, i mean user mode or windows service is better solution.

Depends upon your design. As you mentioned service is always running to if your driver depends upon such requirement then do with service. But it will take more efforts to actually interact with user.

But if your driver can work without any service/app connection as such then go with application.

Comment: We have requirement that service/application needs to be always running any time filter driver can come and ask for some data. So which is the preferred service or application?

Comment: @UmeshaMS, I think service then. But what would happen when there is no user logged in?

Comment: hmmmm, in mini filter driver if i want to get user specific data, then how can we get it. and my idea of running a application is, a service will monitor that application when it kills it will relaunch it.

Comment: @UmeshaMS: A user can kill an application as much as stop a running service. A service will not provide any more protection against termination.